# Gap Between two two dates of different cells

Tags: sql-server

I need help to create one script where i got stuck.

```
MemberId    BeginDate   EndDate Output  
1039725910  3/1/2014    8/10/2014   0   End on 10th August
1039725910  8/11/2014   11/10/2014  1   Start on 11th August, 1 day gap
1039725910  11/11/2014  12/31/2014  1   Start on 11th August, 1 day gap
1166164140  1/1/2014    4/30/2039   0   End on 30 April
1166164140  2/5/2014    12/30/2039  2   Start on 1st May, Here is a 2 days gap
```

Here For one member I have three different begin and end date. for the first records for each member, it would be 0, for the 2nd records, the gap would be (2nd Begindate - 1st EndDate). For 3rd record, The difference would be (3rd Begin date - 2nd EndDate) and so on...I am not able to attach any screenshot.

Kindly help me on this.

Regards,
Ratan

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Also, for the fourth row you have the enddate year as 2039 which would give a diff of -9215 between the fourth and fifth rows, not 2. Is this an error in your example or do you want to disregard the year component and only use month/day?

Comment: I am using Sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` window function together with a self-join to access the previous row partitioned by MemberId like this:

```
select 
    a.MemberId, 
    a.BeginDate, 
    a.EndDate,
    Output = ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, isnull(b.EndDate, a.BeginDate), a.BeginDate), 0) 
from 
    (select *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by memberid order by begindate) from members) a
left join 
    (select *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by memberid order by begindate) from members) b
on a.MemberId = b.MemberId and a.rn - 1 = b.rn
```

With your sample data this would give you:

```
MemberId    BeginDate   EndDate     Output
1039725910  2014-03-01  2014-08-10  0
1039725910  2014-08-11  2014-11-10  1
1039725910  2014-11-11  2014-12-31  1
1166164140  2014-01-01  2039-04-30  0
1166164140  2014-05-02  2039-12-30  -9129
```

If you need to disregard the year component you'll have to do some date arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

Try using query like one given below:

```
select *,
case when rno = 1 then 0
else  datediff(day, begindate,enddate) end as difference
 from 
(select *, row_number() over (partition by MemberId order by MemberId) as rno   from members)
tbl
```

Check below demo code:

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fee01/7)